# Are the Electronic Tools used in the ISS and in the NBL same or different?

Tags: eva, electronics

Most of the time, we see astronauts carrying electronic tools like power drills during an EVA. They undergo training in the Neutral Buoyancy Lab (NBL) for the same. Are the electronic tools used in the ISS and in the NBL same or different? If same, are they waterproof by design? If not, how did they manage to make them work underwater?